# require 'bundler/capistrano' breaks capistrano

Tags: ruby, capistrano, bundler

I added this line to my deploy.rb:

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
```

and now I get this message when I run `cap -T`:

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- bundler/capistrano (LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.5.8/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:152:in `require'
```

Here is some other relevant information:

```
dons-macbook:Gems don$ gem which bundler
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler.rb
dons-macbook:Gems don$ gem which capistrano
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.5.19/lib/capistrano.rb
dons-macbook:Gems don$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-darwin10.4.0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output from `cap -T` says that it's running in Ruby 1.8, not 1.9 (look at the paths to the gems in the output). Check your `PATH`. Even better, use [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com) to manage your Ruby versions and you won't get these kinds of problems.